# Spacy - Phrase Matcher with different attributes

Tags: python, spacy

I have a PhraseMatcher that I define as follows:

```
nlp = English()
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr = 'LOWER')
```

Most of my matching I am find with matching case-insensitive. However, there are a handful of patterns that I want to force to match case-SENSITIVE. Is this possible?  I need to use the PhraseMatcher rather than the EntityRuler.

Comment: If you are matching on both upper and lower case, it doesn't makes sense set the `attr = LOWER`. Matching on the attribute LOWER will result in case-insensitive matching, since only the lowercase token texts are compared.

Comment: I understand. That's what I want since 98% of my patterns should be matched case-insensitive. It is just 4-5 that I want to match verbatim.

Comment: Check the source [code](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/matcher/phrasematcher.pyx), I do not see a way of doing the mix and match. Best if you leave the `attr` out in my opinion. If you find a way around it, please do share.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one `attr` setting. I think the only option is to use two `PhraseMatcher` components.